# Spring Data bean config error: Not an managed type: class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm converting a JdbcTemplate based project to work with Spring Data. I'm getting the "not an managed type: ..." error that some others have described. This usually indicates that Spring Data is not finding the entity class. However, I think I have set things up correctly and am not sure whey I am getting this error.

My basic data configuration is

```
package spittr.config;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
@Import(DataSourceConfig.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories("spittr.data")
public class DataConfig {

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean   entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName("spittr");
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    emf.setPackagesToScan("spittr");
    return emf;
 }

 @Bean
 public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new   HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
      adapter.setShowSql(true);
      adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
      adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
      return adapter;
 }

 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 public static class TransactionConfig {

    @Inject
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }    
  }

  @Bean
  public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  public JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
   return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

}
```

The Spitter entity class is in the package spittr:

```
package spittr;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ScriptAssert;

@ScriptAssert(
        lang = "javascript",
        script = "_this.confirmPassword != null && _this.confirmPassword.equals(_this.password)",
        message = "spitter.password.mismatch.message")

public class Spitter {

  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min=5, max=16, message="{username.size}")
  private String username;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min=5, max=25, message="{password.size}")
  private String password;

  private String confirmPassword;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min=2, max=30, message="{firstName.size}")
  private String firstName;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min=2, max=30, message="{lastName.size}")
  private String lastName;

  @NotNull
  @Email
  private String email;

  public Spitter() {}

  public Spitter(String username, String password, String confirmPassword, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this(null, username, password, confirmPassword, firstName, lastName, email);
  }

  public Spitter(Long id, String username, String password, String confirmPassword, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
  }

  // setters/getters...

}
```

The SpitterDao is in the package spittr.data:

```
package spittr.data;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import spittr.Spitter;

public interface SpitterDao extends JpaRepository<Spitter, Long> {  

    public Spitter findByUsername(String username);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Spitter s SET s.password = :pwd WHERE s.username = :uname")
    public void saveSpitterPassword(@Param("pwd") String password,
                                    @Param("uname") String username);

}
```

I also have a separate service layer, but I don't think this is contributing to the problem. My service layer is defined by the following two files:

```
package spittr.data;

// Interface for SpitterServiceImpl, The Service layer
// implemented in SpitterServiceImpl.java

import spittr.Spitter;

public interface SpitterService {

    public Spitter save(Spitter spitter);

    public Spitter createSpitter(Spitter spitter);

    public Spitter findByUsername(String username);

}
```

and

```
package spittr.data;

import spittr.Spitter;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SpitterServiceImpl implements SpitterService {

    @Inject SpitterDao spitterDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Spitter save(Spitter spitter) {
        return spitterDao.save(spitter);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Spitter createSpitter(Spitter spitter) { 
        Spitter savedSpitter = spitterDao.save(spitter);
        spitterDao.saveSpitterPassword(savedSpitter.getPassword(), savedSpitter.getUsername());
        return savedSpitter;
    }

    @Override
    public Spitter findByUsername(String username) {
        return spitterDao.findByUsername(username);
    }

}
```

The actual exception I'm getting is

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spitterServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: spittr.data.SpitterDao spittr.data.SpitterServiceImpl.spitterDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spitterDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class spittr.Spitter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293)
....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: spittr.data.SpitterDao spittr.data.SpitterServiceImpl.spitterDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spitterDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class spittr.Spitter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class spittr.Spitter
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:169)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to annotate the Spitter class with @Entity. Every Type/Class you want to persist with JPA/Hibernate have to be annoteted with this annotation.

So the Exception says:

- Could not create spitterServiceImpl because of:
- Could not create SpitterDao because of:
- Hibernate say the Type is not a managed Type -> @Entity is missing

PS. you have to annotate the id field with @Id and maybe with some kind ov @GeneratedValue

---

```
@Entity
public class Spitter {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  ...
}
```